# Firebase Functions read and add data in same onCall function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that is triggered when I click a button. Based on the docId I can retrieve the right download URL in Firestore. But I also want to update a specific field (availableDownloads) in my "customers" collection. I can't get it to work.

This code works fine. It returns the download url.

```
exports.getDownloadUrl = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
    var docRef= await db.collection('projects').doc(data.docId);
    return docRef.get().then(function(doc){
        const downloadURL = doc.data().downloadURL;
        return downloadURL;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle error
    });
});
```

However this doesn't. It returns null

```
exports.getDownloadUrl = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
    var docRef= await db.collection('projects').doc(data.docId);
    return docRef.get()
    .then(async function(doc){
        const downloadURL = doc.data().downloadURL;
        const userRef = await db.collection('customers').doc(context.auth.uid);
        return userRef.update({
            availableDownloads: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)
        }).then(()=> {
            return downloadURL;
        }).catch((error)=> {
            
        })
        
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle error
    });
});
```

Comment: It's best not to mix async/await with then/catch.  If you're able to use async/await anywhere, use it everywhere to simplify your code.  Also consider adding logging to figure out how this code actually executes.  We can't see your data or any of the variables here.

Comment: Ok thanks, I might do that.

Comment: Also: `await` is not needed here `await db.collection('customers').doc(context.auth.uid)`.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I noticed. Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that [`.update()` is an asynchronous function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) so you need an `await` in front of `userRef.update(...)`.

You should also consider sticking to either arrow functions (`() => {}`) or anonymous functions (`function () {}`), but that's just a stylistic note. :)

ETA: as Frank van Puffelen pointed out, you *don't* need `await`s for simply declaring a DocumentReference since those are not async functions. (looking at the line `var docRef= await db.collection('projects').doc(data.docId);`).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the potential problems due to the mix of `async/await` with `then/catch`, **your main problem is due to** [variable scoping](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript#variable-scope). The `downloadURL` variable is a local variable declared inside the first `then()` block and is therefore not accessible in the second `then()` block.

You can easily see the problem with the following code:

```
  function later(delay, value) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay, value));
  }

  later(500, 'value1')
    .then((value) => {
      console.log('First then block: ' + value);
      const downloadURL = value;
      return later(1000, 'value2');
    })
    .then((value) => {
      console.log('Second then block: ' + value);
      console.log('Second then block: ' + downloadURL); // Here it is going to throw an error
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

---

You need to declare the `downloadURL` variable in the scope of the Cloud Function, as follows:

```
exports.getDownloadUrl = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    let downloadURL;
    const docRef = db.collection('projects').doc(data.docId);
    return docRef.get()
        .then((doc) => {
            downloadURL = doc.data().downloadURL;
            const userRef = db.collection('customers').doc(context.auth.uid);
            return userRef.update({
                availableDownloads: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)
            });
        })
        .then(() => {
            return downloadURL;
        }).catch((error) => {
            // Handle error
        })
});
```

---

Note that the above code does not use async/await. If you want to use async/await, do as follows:

```
exports.getDownloadUrl = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    try {
        const docRef = db.collection('projects').doc(data.docId);

        const doc = await docRef.get();
        const downloadURL = doc.data().downloadURL;

        const userRef = db.collection('customers').doc(context.auth.uid);
        await userRef.update({
            availableDownloads: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)
        })

        return downloadURL;
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle error
    }

});
```

You can see that with this code, due to the fact that it is simplified by using async/await, there is no more complexity due to variable scoping.

Comment: @HKN Hello, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Thanks, it does work with the declaration I did. However it does make more sense they way you did it.

Comment: @HKN Thanks for the feedback. If you think my answer brought you some value, please upvote it.